# Porque obtengo una respuesta vacía en flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hola soy nuevo en flutter estoy tratando de hacer peticiones get con un valor introducido en una caja de texto, luego al presionar el botón hago con este método :

```
getDataPorArea('BuscarRegistroEmbarques', _ot);
```

El método para extraer la informacion con el Future es:

```
Future getDataPorArea(area, ot) async {
const _baseUrl = 'servidor';
final url = Uri.http(_baseUrl, 'api/Actualizacion/$area/$ot');
final rsp = await http.get(url);
final List<dynamic> dataList = json.decode(rsp.body);
if (dataList.first == 0) {      
  print("Sin Datos");   
  return registroSinDatosFromJson(dataList.toString());
} else {      
  print("Con datos");
  return buscarRegistroFromJson(rsp.body);
    }
  }
```

Al imprimir en consola solo me sale lo siguiente:

```
I/flutter (25996): caso calidad
I/flutter (25996):
I/flutter (25996): Sin Datos
```

pero si le vuelvo a pulsar el botón

```
I/flutter (25996): caso calidad
I/flutter (25996): [0]
I/flutter (25996): Sin Datos
```

No se como hacerlo de una manera en que pueda retrasar el imprimir la variable

Comment: Como retrasar el imprimir la variable?

Comment: Bueno no solo retrasarlo, sino que necesito ocupar los datos que vienen de la respuesta

Comment: intenta primero validar que la respuesta del get sea 200, valida el rsp.status == 200

Comment: por ejemplo responde siempre `[0]` o  `[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "ot": "2           ",
        "auth_Area": "NO",
        "comentarios": "Aceptado",
        "fecha": "2022-05-05T00:00:00",
        "area": "EMBARQUES",
        "nombre": "Trabajador 1,
        "numTrabajador": "2655",
        "otNavigation": null
    }
]`  no se como validar para acceder a sus propiedades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según los comentarios, lo que quieres hacer es acceder a las atributos que te devuelve el `json`, es bueno que siempre valides que la respuesta de la llamada al servicio sea 200, así que primero tendrás que validar eso, luego el `List<dynamic>` lo reemplazamos por un `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` porque lo que retorna el json es una lista de mapas:

```
    Future getDataPorArea(area, ot) async {
        const _baseUrl = 'servidor';
        final url = Uri.http(_baseUrl, 'api/Actualizacion/$area/$ot');
        final rsp = await http.get(url);
        if(rsp.statusCode == 200){
            final dataList = json.decode(rsp.body);
            if (dataList.isEmpty) {      
               print("Sin Datos");   
               return registroSinDatosFromJson(dataList.toString());
            } else {      
               print("Con datos");
             //En tal caso que si haya datos, accedes al primer 
             //valor por ejemplo el nombre el índice 0
               print("${dataList[0]['nombre']}")
               //return buscarRegistroFromJson(rsp.body);
              }
            }
          }
```

Espero y esa respuesta te sirva

Comment: al utilizarlo me arroja el siguiente comentario  `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>')`

Comment: Cierto, elimina el List<Map<String, dynamic>> y dejala como variable de tipo final

Comment: Me sirvió mucho, muchas gracias!